# EPiServer Empty application after run asking credential

Tags: episerver, optimizely

I have created an empty EPiServer MVC application, and when I run the project, it's prompting me to enter a username and password. I haven't set up any user accounts, and I'm not sure what credentials to use. Can someone assist me with this?[image]

Comment: version 11 or 12?

Answer (score 0):

In web.config, you have a section like this. Change this to allow all users access to admin mode, then you can enter admin mode without having to log in, and create your user. Change the configuration back afterward.

```
<location path="Episerver/CMS/admin">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="WebAdmins" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```